# Objectify Ruby Hashes from/to JSON API

Tags: json, ruby, rest, hash

I just released a ruby gem to use some JSON over HTTP API:

https://github.com/solyaris/blomming_api

My naif ruby code just convert complex/nested JSON data structures returned by API endpoints (json_data) to ruby Hashes ( hash_data), in a flat one-to-one transaltion (JSON to ruby hash and viceversa). Tat's fine, but...

I would like a programming interface more "high level".
Maybe instatiating a class Resource for every endpoint, but I'm confused about a smart implementation.

Let me explain with an abstract code.

Let say I have a complex/nested JSON received by an API,
usually an Array of Hashes, recursively nested as here below (imagination example):

```
json_data = '[{
    "commute": {
        "minutes": 0,
        "startTime": "Wed May 06 22:14:12 EDT 2014",
        "locations": [
            {
                "latitude": "40.4220061",
                "longitude": "40.4220061"
            },
            {
                "latitude": "40.4989909",
                "longitude": "40.48989805"
            },            
            {
                "latitude": "40.4111169",
                "longitude": "40.42222869"
            }            
        ]
    }
},
{
    "commute": {
        "minutes": 2,
        "startTime": "Wed May 28 20:14:12 EDT 2014",
        "locations": [
            {
                "latitude": "43.4220063",
                "longitude": "43.4220063"
            }
        ]
    }
}]'
```

At the moment what I do, when I receive a similar JSON form an API is just:

```
# from JSON to hash 
hash_data = JSON.load json_data

# and to assign values:
coords = hash_data.first["commute"]["locations"].last
coords["longitude"] = "40.00" # was "40.4111169"
coords["latitude"] = "41.00" # was "40.42222869"
```

that's ok, but with awfull/confusing syntax.
Instead, I probably would enjoy something like:

```
# create object Resource from hash
res = Resource.create( hash_data )

# ... some processing

# assign a "nested" variables: longitude, latitude of object: res
coords = res.first.commute.locations.last
coords.longitude = "40.00" # was "40.4111169"
coords.latitude = "41.00" # was "40.42222869"

# ... some processing

# convert modified object: res into an hash again:
modified_hash = res.save

# and probably at least I'll recover to to JSON:
modified_json = JSON.dump modified_hash
```

I  read intresting posts:
http://pullmonkey.com/2008/01/06/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-a-class-object/
http://www.goodercode.com/wp/convert-your-hash-keys-to-object-properties-in-ruby/

and copying Kerry Wilson' code, I sketched the implementation here below:

```
class Resource

  def self.create (hash)
    new ( hash)
  end

  def initialize ( hash)
    hash.to_obj
  end

  def save
    # or to_hash() 
    # todo! HELP! (see later)
  end

end


class ::Hash
  # add keys to hash
  def to_obj
    self.each do |k,v|

      v.to_obj if v.kind_of? Hash
      v.to_obj if v.kind_of? Array

      k=k.gsub(/\.|\s|-|\/|\'/, '_').downcase.to_sym

      ## create and initialize an instance variable for this key/value pair
      self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)

      ## create the getter that returns the instance variable
      self.class.send(:define_method, k, proc{self.instance_variable_get("@#{k}")})

      ## create the setter that sets the instance variable
      self.class.send(:define_method, "#{k}=", proc{|v| self.instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)})
    end
    return self
  end
end

class ::Array
  def to_obj
    self.map { |v| v.to_obj }
  end 
end
#------------------------------------------------------------
```

BTW, I studied a bit ActiveResource project (was part of Rails if I well understood).
ARes could be great for my scope but the problem is ARes have a bit too "strict" presumption of full REST APIs...
In my case server API are not completely RESTfull in the way ARes would expect...
All in all I would do a lot of work to subclass / modify ARes behaviours
and at the moment I discarded the idea to use ActiveResource

QUESTIONS:

1. someone could help me to realize the `save()` method on the above code (I'm really bad with recursive methods... :-( ) ?
2. Does exist some gem that to the above sketched `hash_to_object()` and `object_to_hash()` translation ?
3. What do you think about that "automatic" objectifying of an "arbitrary" hash coming from a JSON over http APIs ?
   I mean:  I see the great pro that I do not need to client-side static-wire data structures, allowing to be flexible to possible server side variations.
   But on the other hand, doing this automatic objectify, there is a possible cons of a side effect to allow security issues ... like malicious JSON injection (possible untrasted communication net ...)

What do you think about all this ? Any suggestion is welcome!
Sorry for my long post and my ruby language meta-programming hazards :-)

UPDATE 2: I'm still interested reading opinions about question point 3:
Pros/Cons to create Resource class for every received JSON
Pros/Cons to create static (preemptive attributes) / automatic/dynamic nested objects

UPDATE 1: long reply to Simone:
thanks, you are right Mash have a sweet .to_hash() method:

```
require 'json'
require 'hashie'

json_data = '{
    "commute": {
        "minutes": 0,
        "startTime": "Wed May 06 22:14:12 EDT 2014",
        "locations": [
            {
                "latitude": "40.4220061",
                "longitude": "40.4220061"
            },
            {
                "latitude": "40.4989909",
                "longitude": "40.48989805"
            },            
            {
                "latitude": "40.4111169",
                "longitude": "40.42222869"
            }            
        ]
    }
}'

# trasforma in hash
hash = JSON.load json_data

puts hash

res = Hashie::Mash.new hash

# assign a "nested" variables: longitude, latitude of object: res
coords = res.commute.locations.last
coords.longitude = "40.00" # was "40.4111169"
coords.latitude = "41.00" # was "40.42222869"

puts; puts "longitude: #{res.commute.locations.last.longitude}"
puts "latitude: #{res.commute.locations.last.latitude}"

modified_hash = res.to_hash
puts; puts modified_hash
```

Comment: My `shenanigans` gem has a `Hash#to_ostruct` method that was written with YAML/JSON in mind. Maybe that's enough for you to create objects out of your hashes, if not it should at least help with recursion. http://rubydoc.info/gems/shenanigans/1.0.9/Hash:to_ostruct

Comment: I would avoid openstructs anyway thank you Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is provided by a few gem. One of the most known is [`Hashie`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie), specifically the class [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie).

> Mash is an extended Hash that gives simple pseudo-object functionality that can be built from hashes and easily extended. It is designed to be used in RESTful API libraries to provide easy object-like access to JSON and XML parsed hashes.

`Mash` also supports multi-level objects.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs and level of nesting, you may get away with an [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

I was working with a simple test stub. `Hashie` would have worked well, but was a bigger tool than I needed (and added dependency).

Comment: Though I can't state which versions, nor whether the problem still exists, Hashie has been culprit behind memory leaks in systems I've worked with in the past. OpenStruct is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of ruby (at least 2.3 possibly older) allow parsing into an OpenStruct directly.

Given the json_data from the question:

```
commute_data = JSON.parse json_data, {object_class: OpenStruct}
commute_data.first.commute.locations.last.latitude

#=> "40.4111169"
```

json_data is parsed into an OpenStruct object with accessors without adding dependencies to your project.