# Nested Hash from JSON structure - Critical look

Tags: ruby, json, hash

I'm new on ruby, I come from C/C++. 
I'm currently working on data integration between a partner and me. 
I get the API response with httparty and then parse it with JSON.parse.

The hash result is like multi level nested ( around 5-6 levels )
Initially, since I'm new on ruby, I wanted to develop naturally, without thinking of number of methods, number of line in methods, the only goal was to clearly separate each extraction from another in distinct methods.

The extraction from this nested hash is conditional extract, what I mean is there is multiples object of the same structure inside the hash.

And my extraction is like something like this:

```
 if  get_flight(json_response) == blabla_id
     stored_blabla_id = blabla_id
 end
```

then later

```
get_departure_place_from_flight(json_response, stored_blabla_id)
```

I read many articles about obectifying hash like [this good one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855664/objectify-ruby-hashes-from-to-json-api), or building some engines-extractor that getting value based on key passed in arguments.

Since I'm getting a really huge json response,  and since I'm not extracting all the values but specifics one, I'm wondering if its not bad for usage/performance.

My point :  the class is working properly **BUT**: I have 25 methods in one class,  and the content of theses methods are like a direct access from the nested hash. I find it very ugly.

I was wondering since I have 2 request methods to the API, 1 method dedicated to construct URL, and the others one dedicated to extraction from the JSON response ,  is it appropriate to split the class into modules?

Or, is this kind of ugly class common in JSON parse/extracting value from whatever API's?

Comment: Maybe look at the `Struct` class since you already know the attributes you want.

Comment: Without a minimal example of your JSON and code demonstrating the problem you're having, we're going to have to use our imaginations to recreate both, which is not very useful, and actually wastes our time. Please clarify your question with both. Good coding should avoid duplication, but the number of methods in a class is irrelevant if they are needed and you avoid redundancy. Parsed JSON results in a hash or an array, so use standard hash accessors and abstract those if you want, it's your choice.